# How to print information from a pdb file, using the cmd module in PyMOL?

Tags: python, loops, cmd, pdb, pymol

I want to extract information from several pdb files, using the cmd python module in order to integrate pymol, to extract information. More specifically I want to find all the metals in the pdb files.

Using the cmd command its pretty straightforward to perform this task as you can type cmd.select ("m", "metals"). However this does not print the resulting number of metals found.

Looking around on the internet I found the Iterate command, but I have no idea how to use it. (http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate).

Below is my non working code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/")

import __main__
__main__.pymol_argv = [ 'pymol', '-qc']

import pymol
from pymol import cmd

import glob
a = glob.glob("C:/Python27/Metal/*.pdb")

for file in a:
    f= open (file, 'r')
    cmd.iterate ("m","metals")
    print ?

pymol.finish_launching()
pymol.cmd.quit()
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please edit the question and fix the syntax highlighting and indention?

Comment: Did you see [the example in the documentation](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate#PYMOL_API)?

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer , having in folder `Metals` pdb files : `1qgu.pdb` ,`4a4j.pdb` and `5yc3.pdb`  with code:

```
import glob


from pymol import cmd, stored


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')



a = glob.glob("Metals/*.pdb")

print(a)

stored.metals_dict = {}

for file in a :
    
    print('File : ' , file.rstrip('.pdb').lstrip('Metals/'))
    
    stored.metals_dict[file.rstrip('.pdb').lstrip('Metals/')] = []
    try: 
        
        cmd.load( file , file.rstrip('.pdb').lstrip('Metals/'))
        
        sel = cmd.select('selected' , 'metals')
        
        print(sel)
        
        print(cmd.get_names('objects' , 0,  'selected'))
        
        cmd.iterate('selected' , "stored.metals_dict[model] += [(ID, segi, chain, resn, int(resi), type)]") 
        
        cmd.delete(file.rstrip('.pdb').lstrip('Metals/'))
        
    except Exception as e :
        
        print(e)

print('\n stored.metals_dict -------> ', stored.metals_dict,'\n\n')

print('\n stored.metals_dict.keys() -------> ' , stored.metals_dict.keys())

for keys in stored.metals_dict :
    
    print('\n\n', keys ,' : ', stored.metals_dict[keys] ,'\n', len(stored.metals_dict[keys]),'\n\n')
```

I get output below :

```
['Metals/1qgu.pdb', 'Metals/4a4j.pdb', 'Metals/5yc3.pdb']
File :  1qgu
 PyMOL not running, entering library mode (experimental)
39
['1qgu']
File :  4a4j
1
['4a4j']
File :  5yc3
2
['5yc3']

 stored.metals_dict ------->  {'1qgu': [(15548, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15549, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15550, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15551, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15552, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15553, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15554, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15555, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15565, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15566, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15567, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15568, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15573, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15574, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15575, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15576, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15533, '', 'A', 'MG', 3001, 'HETATM'), 
(15601, '', 'B', 'MG', 3002, 'HETATM'), (15602, '', 'B', 'MG', 3003, 'HETATM'), 
(15603, '', 'B', 'MG', 3004, 'HETATM'), (15635, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15636, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15637, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15638, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15639, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15640, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15641, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), 
(15642, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15652, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15653, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15654, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'),
 (15655, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15660, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15661, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15662, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), 
(15663, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15620, '', 'C', 'MG', 3005, 'HETATM'), 
(15672, '', 'D', 'MG', 3006, 'HETATM'), (15673, '', 'D', 'MG', 3007, 'HETATM')], 

'4a4j': [(520, '', 'A', 'ZN', 71, 'HETATM')], 

'5yc3': [(529, '', 'A', 'ZN', 101, 'HETATM'), (530, '', 'A', 'ZN', 102, 'HETATM')]} 



 stored.metals_dict.keys() ------->  dict_keys(['1qgu', '4a4j', '5yc3'])


 1qgu  :  [(15548, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15549, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15550, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15551, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15552, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15553, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15554, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15555, '', 'A', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15565, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15566, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15567, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15568, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15573, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15574, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15575, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15576, '', 'A', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15533, '', 'A', 'MG', 3001, 'HETATM'), (15601, '', 'B', 'MG', 3002, 'HETATM'), (15602, '', 'B', 'MG', 3003, 'HETATM'), (15603, '', 'B', 'MG', 3004, 'HETATM'), (15635, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15636, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15637, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15638, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15639, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15640, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15641, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15642, '', 'C', 'CFM', 503, 'HETATM'), (15652, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15653, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15654, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15655, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15660, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15661, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15662, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15663, '', 'C', 'CLF', 505, 'HETATM'), (15620, '', 'C', 'MG', 3005, 'HETATM'), (15672, '', 'D', 'MG', 3006, 'HETATM'), (15673, '', 'D', 'MG', 3007, 'HETATM')] 
 39 




 4a4j  :  [(520, '', 'A', 'ZN', 71, 'HETATM')] 
 1 




 5yc3  :  [(529, '', 'A', 'ZN', 101, 'HETATM'), (530, '', 'A', 'ZN', 102, 'HETATM')] 
 2
```